# django allauth - get() returned more than one User -- it returned 2! in production

Tags: python, django, django-allauth, google-signin

I'm trying to add google auth service to my site, it is working correctly in localhost, but in the server, I've got an error when a new user tries to sign up although the old users can connect their account to google account without any problems

```
get() returned more than one User -- it returned 2!
```

> there is no duplicated either in the user model or social account
> model.

before I added social auth users could only log in or sign in with their email addresses, so now my `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` is like that:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
        'user_profile.backends.EmailBackend',
'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',)
```

and my `EmailBackend` file in like this:

```
class EmailBackend(ModelBackend):
    def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None, **kwargs):
        UserModel = get_user_model()
        try:
            user = UserModel.objects.get(email=username.lower())
        except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
            return None
        else:
            if user.check_password(password):
                return user
        return None


class MySocialAccountAdapter(DefaultSocialAccountAdapter):
    def pre_social_login(self, request, sociallogin):
        user = sociallogin.user
        if user.id:
            return
        try:
            customer = User.objects.get(email=user.email)  # if user exists, connect the account to the existing account and login
            sociallogin.state['process'] = 'connect'
            perform_login(request, customer, 'none')
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            pass
```

and in my `settings.py`:

```
SOCIALACCOUNT_ADAPTER = 'user_profile.backends.MySocialAccountAdapter'
```

thanks a lot, it has been a disaster

Comment: It means that there are two or more users with the same `email` address (that is apparently the `username`).

Comment: @willemvanonsem but I'm sure there isn't any duplicate, this error always come with any new signup

Comment: I get the same thing, and email is a unique primary key. I think its to do with multiple session linked to a cookie or something like that.